# Can I connect the wifi and create hotspot with only 1 wireless card?

Tags: wireless, hot-spot

It seems that with one wireless network card, I can either connect the wifi or create hotspot. But in windows, I can connect the wifi, create hostspot and share the network with the hotspot as the same time. In the ubuntu, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Also in Linux this should be possible.

In the terminal type in

```
sudo iw list
```

and look for the part, where `interface combinations` are mentioned.
This will tell you about the capabilities of your WiFi hardware/driver.
You get info about which modes can be used in parallel (if supported) and how many channels are available for this (on most standard HW you will be limited to a single channel).

I have not tried it myself, but here is one possible way to [setup an AP in parallel to being connected to another AP](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/wifi-ap/docs/simultaneous-sta-ap-mode) in Ubuntu.

Comment: Just to help where to look for it, for me it's called: `valid interface combinations:` and it's a top-level list item, **not** nested (like several things in the list).

Comment: Link is returning 404. I think new link is https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/simultaneous-sta-ap-mode/19964

Answer (score 2):

Update on @HIMANSHU GARG answer with installation steps.

**Step 1:**

First, check whether your wireless card can create a hotspot or not while connected to a wifi network. (as mentioned by @oh.dae.su)

-> run `sudo iw list` and look for `valid interface combinations:` in output

- My output screenshot (I have 2 channels):
  [image]

**Step 2:**

Install `Linux Wifi Hotspot`. This one provides both command line and GUI based interfaces. (Reference: [Github repository link](https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot.git))

- Install ubuntu package dependencies and make package:
  `sudo apt install -y libgtk-3-dev build-essential gcc g++ pkg-config make hostapd libqrencode-dev libpng-dev`
- Follow these commands in terminal:
  `git clone https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot`
  `cd linux-wifi-hotspot`
  `make`
  `sudo make install`

###### Output screenshots:

1. check your wifi/internet adapter name using `ifconfig` (e.g. for me it's `wlp6s0`)
   [image]
2. Wifi hotspot running in parallel with wifi connected
   [image]

###### System specs:

- Tested on: **Ubuntu 20.04**
- My wifi card info (run `sudo lshw -C network`):
  Description: Wireless interface
  Product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
  Vendor: Intel Corporation

Answer (score 1):

Note :- (Tried on Ubuntu 18.04 and can be used only for linux)

To turn on Wifi hotspot to share the intenet without disconnecting from WiFi (means both are running at same time). This tool can be helpful for this. Follow the steps given there. This tool has a nice GUI and easy to use.

[image: GUI Image]

Answer (score 0):

Far as I know you can't. In Linux.

You can connect your PC with a cable and then make wifi card as hot-spot.

Or connect, for example, with eternal wifi and make external/USB as hot-spot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked for me on my Laptop running Ubuntu 18.04:

https://github.com/oblique/create_ap

It's not beeing maintained anymore, but it workes like a charm and is simple to run.

Open up a terminal and enter the following:

1. git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap.git
2. cd create_ap/
3. make install
4. sudo create_ap wlan0 wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase

Line 4 will create a hotspot, if you close the terminal the hotspot will shutdown.

wlan0 is my wireless adapter, find yours with using "ip addr" in a terminal. "MyAccesspoint" and "MyPassPhrase" can be changed to what you would like.

Comment: Maybe you could add the steps here for reference?

Comment: Yup, I'll add them